# I am trying to add and remove class in a divtag which couldnt do

Tags: jquery

I wanna add class or alter the existing class name..but i couldnt do it.

```
<div id="vote2" style='.'"background:url(images/btn_active.gif)no-repeat">

$("#vote2").addClass("vtbtn");
```

And also i am trying to remove jte existing class name which i couldnt accomplish either.

```
<div id="vote2" class="vtbtn" style='.'"background:url(images/btn_active.gif)no-repeat">

$("#vote2").removeClass("vtbtn");
```

i got my css as

```
.vtbtn{ cursor:pointer;}
```

But whenever i click on the button ,its not adding the class name..and its not removing existing class name as well

this is my full script

```
   $("#vote2").click( function() {
        $(this).addClass("vtbtn");  //or $("vtbtn").....               
        $("#vote1").css("background","url(images/btn_inactive.gif) no-repeat 0 0")
                ;})
```

Comment: what you want? there is a class vtbtn you can edit this name and do replace the same name where ever you see this name.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you have in your jQuery (your style attribute doesn't need that '.' in it) so I would guess perhaps you have more than one item with `vote2` id on your page?

Comment: Ry Van? What is the sequence of characters immediately after the style attribute for? (singlequote dot singlequote)

Answer (score 2):

You have some syntax errors in your style attributes. Try this:

```
<div id="vote2" style="background: url(images/btn_active.gif) no-repeat;">
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want change classes you could use the toggle function.

$("#vote2").toggleClass("vtbtn");

this will toggle any classes to just vtbtn.

link:
http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: Your answer doesn't really address why he's having an issue with addClass() and removeClass().

Comment: Well he wanted to change the class info from the beginning. so why not use toggle? he said add or change so toggle does what he needs as well.